# Code Injection doesn't work on Vista or Win7?

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-vista, windows-xp, code-injection

So I had to two friends test the executable on their Vista & Win7 operating systems. Neither had the injected code executed (even when Run as Administrator) but the console open/closed. Does code injection via `WriteProcessMemory` and `CreateRemoteThread` still work on Vista or Win7?

**The Code**

Compiled using /RTCu on Visual Studio 2008 to prevent process crashing while on Windows XP after the remote thread terminates.

**CodeInjector.h**

```
#ifndef CODEINJECTOR_H
#define CODEINJECTOR_H

typedef HANDLE(WINAPI *GETPROC)();
typedef HMODULE(WINAPI *PLOADLIBRARYA)(const char *dll);
typedef LPVOID(WINAPI *PGETPROCADDRESS)(HMODULE mod, const char *func);
typedef int (WINAPI *FNMESSAGEBOX)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);

typedef struct _IAT {
    PLOADLIBRARYA pLoadLibraryA;
    PGETPROCADDRESS pGetProcAddress;
    FNMESSAGEBOX fnMessageBox;
} IAT;

typedef struct _DATA {
    void *szData[256];
} DATA;

typedef struct _FNARGS {
    LPVOID pIat;
    LPVOID pData;
} FNARGS;

#endif  /* CODEINJECTOR_H */
```

**CodeInjector.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

#include "CodeInjector.h"

using namespace std;

HANDLE getHandleByName(const char* nameWnd)
{
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, nameWnd);

    if (hWnd == 0) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot find window" << std::endl;
    } else {
        DWORD pId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pId);

        HANDLE hToken;
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;
        if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) {
            LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);
            tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
            AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, 0, &tkp, sizeof (tkp), NULL, NULL);
        }

        HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pId);

        if (!hProc) {
            std::cerr << "Cannot open process: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        } else {
            return hProc;
        }cout << hProc;
        getchar();
    }

    return false;
}

static DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(FNARGS *info)
{
    if (info == NULL || info->pIat == NULL || info->pData == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    IAT *iat = (IAT *)info->pIat;
    DATA *data = (DATA *)info->pData;

    iat->fnMessageBox(NULL, (char*)data->szData[1], (char*)data->szData[0], MB_OK);

    return 0;
}

static void ThreadFuncEnd() {}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hProc = getHandleByName("Calculator");

    DWORD CodeSize = (DWORD) & ThreadFuncEnd - (DWORD) & ThreadFunc;

    IAT hIAT;

    DWORD hLibModule;
    HMODULE hKernel = LoadLibraryA("kernel32.dll");
    HMODULE hUser32 = LoadLibraryA("user32.dll");

    hIAT.pLoadLibraryA = (PLOADLIBRARYA)GetProcAddress(hKernel, "LoadLibraryA");
    hIAT.pGetProcAddress = (PGETPROCADDRESS)GetProcAddress(hKernel, "GetProcAddress");
    hIAT.fnMessageBox = (FNMESSAGEBOX)GetProcAddress(hUser32, "MessageBoxA");

    LPVOID hIATMemAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, sizeof (IAT), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, hIATMemAddr, (LPVOID) & hIAT, sizeof (IAT), NULL);

    DATA hData;
    LPVOID hDataMemAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, sizeof (DATA), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    hData.szData[0] = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, 64, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    hData.szData[1] = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, 64, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    hData.szData[2] = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, 64, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    hData.szData[3] = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, 64, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    char tmp[64];

    strcpy(tmp, "Caption");
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, hData.szData[0], (LPVOID) & tmp, sizeof (tmp), NULL);

    strcpy(tmp, "Message");
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, hData.szData[1], (LPVOID) & tmp, sizeof (tmp), NULL);

    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, hDataMemAddr, (LPVOID) &hData, sizeof (DATA), NULL);

    FNARGS tInfo;
    tInfo.pIat = hIATMemAddr;
    tInfo.pData = hDataMemAddr;

    LPVOID hInfoMemAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, sizeof (FNARGS), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, hInfoMemAddr, (LPVOID) & tInfo, sizeof (FNARGS), NULL);

    LPVOID CodeMemAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, CodeSize, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, CodeMemAddr, (LPVOID) & ThreadFunc, CodeSize, NULL);

    HANDLE hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)CodeMemAddr, hInfoMemAddr, 0, NULL);

    WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeThread(hRemoteThread, &hLibModule);

    CloseHandle(hProc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you want us to debug this for you? It's not clear what you want and what the error is?

Comment: Well, it compiles fine but it doesn't inject code into other processes in Vista & Win7. There are various methods to inject code so I posted my implementation for reference. I'm not sure how to check why code injection isn't working and that's what I'd like to know.

Comment: There are a lot of APIs you're calling where you don't check the return value so it's hard to tell.  You should track down the problem some more, right now there are too many variables.

Comment: Old question, but I have UAC disabled on Win7 x64 and injection via the CreateRemoteThread & LoadLibrary method worked for me, without even running as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a surprise. Vista and Windows 7 have increased security. Lots of malware used Code Injection as one of the steps to bypass security mechanisms on Windows XP, and I'm glad to see Microsoft fixed this.